# regexp to match table name in sql create table statement

Tags: javascript, sql, regex, node.js

I need some help with a regular expression i'm making a program with node js that loads sql with tables structure and executes them,i store in array all tables names that should be created.
I have the following code that it works but i would like to know if there is a better way to do it. Thanks in advance..

```
for (var i = 0, max = list.length; i < max; i++) {
    (function (j) {
        var sql = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'sql', list[j]), "utf8").toString();
        // var stmts = sql.match(/[_\"a-zA-Z0-9\s\,\(\)\*-]+;/gi);
        var tables = sql.match(/CREATE\sTABLE\s\"?[A-Z0a-z0-9_]+\"?/gi);
        if (tables) {
            for (var k = 0, max = tables.length; k < max; k++) {
                tables[k] = tables[k].replace(/create\stable\s+?/gi, '');
                tables[k] = tables[k].replace(/\"/, '');
                console.log("========= table name ==========");
                console.log(tables[k]);
            }
        }
    })(i);
}
```

Comment: Better in what way?  Faster?  More memory efficient?  More readable?  Less bug-prone?  More flexible?  All of these things, and more, could be implied by the term *better*, but they are often conflicting goals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To tell the truth, there is some duplication in your code: you match longer substrings with a regex and then perform additional regex replacements again using regex. I suggest using just one regex to match and capture what we need at once:

```js
var sql = "create table  \"myTable\"     CREATE  TABLE  new_table12    --";
var re = /CREATE\s+TABLE\s+\"?(\w+)/gi;
var tables = [];
var m;
while((m=re.exec(sql)) !== null) {
      tables.push(m[1]);
      document.write("= table name =<br/>"); // for demo only
      document.write(m[1]+"<br/>");          // for demo only
 }
alert(tables);
```

The regex `CREATE\s+TABLE\s+\"?(\w+)` matches `create` and `table` in a case-insensitive way and any whitespace (1 or more) in-between. A double quote is optional, and after it `\w+` matches and capture the table name. This shorthand class stands for `[A-Za-z0-9_]`, so we can shorten the code a bit.

Then, we cannot use `String#match`, since we need to find multiple matches and grab captured texts. Thus, I suggest using `RegExp#exec`. The captured texts will be in `m[1]` that I use to populate `tables` variable.

Comment: I didn't know about the exec method,now i know Thank you

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion i think i already marked it as aswered